# Build Fails Using GCC-11 Due to Some Missing Standard Library Headers

Tags: c++, gcc, std, ubuntu-22.04, gcc11

After upgrading to gcc-11, which is shipped with Ubuntu 22.04, I started to get new compiler errors due to some missing Standard Library header files. Whereas previous gcc versions don't.

When I started to look into it, I learned from [Porting to GCC 11](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/porting_to.html) page, under the "Header dependency changes" section, that this is a new behavior due to some new specs in the standard itself.

Now, my question is: does the implementation of a particular C++ standard (i.e. C++17) change from one gcc version to another (i.e. gcc-9 and gcc-11)? I mean, how can the build fail if I'm building with different gcc versions but against the same C++ standard version (i.e. -std=c++17)?

And is that C++ Standard Library new requirement - of not to include other headers that were being used internally by the library - part of C++17 or C++20?

**To get over this...**
I manually included those header files where they were missing, and the build just succeeded.
However, I was expecting behavior to be consistent when I build against a certain C++ version with different gcc versions. Or, am I missing something?

Comment: IIRC headers are allowed to declare stuff that the standard doesn't say they should, as long as they declare all the stuff it does say.

Comment: Of course the implementation of a specific standard can change from one compiler version to the next. Bugs get fixed, missing features get added, etc.

Comment: *"due to some new specs in the standard itself."* -- I do not see this in your linked resource. By my reading, the change is due to changes in the *library* that implements the standard, not changes to the standard. What makes you think there was a change to the standard?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [JaMiT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9837301/jamit) note, I realized that I got the note from GCC wrong.
It's only their implementation of the Standard that got changed in GCC 11, and not the Standard itself.

When you thoroughly read the referenced section from [that article](https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-11/porting_to.html), you can see that.

> **Header dependency changes**
>
> Some C++ Standard Library headers have been changed to no longer
> include other headers that were being used internally by the library.
> As such, C++ programs that used standard library components without
> including the right headers will no longer compile.
>
> The following headers are used less widely in libstdc++ and may need
> to be included explicitly when compiled with GCC 11:
>
> ```
> <limits>  (for std::numeric_limits)
> <memory>  (for std::unique_ptr, std::shared_ptr etc.)
> <utility> (for std::pair, std::tuple_size, std::index_sequence etc.)
> <thread>  (for members of namespace std::this_thread.)
> ```